# Multilpe matrix (mxm) and vector (n), wich are unequal, so get a (three dimensional matrix) mxmxn matrix

Tags: matrix

For example I have this matrix:

```
mk = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

and I'd like it to multiple with this:

```
ot = Table[5, {4}]
```

> ```
> {5,5,5,5}
> ```

to get this one:

```
{{{ 5, 5, 5, 5}, {10,10,10,10}, {15,15,15}}, 
 {{20,20,20,20}, {25,25 ...}...}...}
```

but `KroneckerProduct` gives me `3` rows instead of a `3 x 3 x 4` matrix (similar but not identical). Of course I have really large lists...

```
KroneckerProduct[mk, ot]
```

> ```
> {{5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15}, 
>  {20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 30}, 
>  {35, 35, 35, 35, 40, 40, 40, 40, 45, 45, 45, 45}}
> ```

Comment: Use `Map` at the second level `Map[{5, 5, 5, 5} # &, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {2}]`.

Comment: How about `Outer[Times, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {5, 5, 5, 5}]`?

Comment: Thank you! These were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it:

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
v = {5, 5, 5, 5};

KroneckerProduct[m, {{v}}]
```

> ```
> {{{5, 5, 5, 5}, {10, 10, 10, 10}, {15, 15, 15, 15}}, {{20, 20, 20, 20}, {25, 25, 25, 
>    25}, {30, 30, 30, 30}}, {{35, 35, 35, 35}, {40, 40, 40, 40}, {45, 45, 45, 45}}}
> ```

At least in version 7 `Outer` as recommended by Jacob is somewhat faster however:

```
m = RandomReal[9, {50, 100}];
v = RandomReal[9, 127];

KroneckerProduct[m, {{v}}] ~Do~ {500} // Timing // First
Outer[Times, m, v] ~Do~ {500}         // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.373
>
> 0.733
> ```

Comment: +1 and the timings are similar in proportion on version 9